# Correct use of relations/constraints when deleting a complete user account

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

How do you handle constraints when you want to delete a complete user account with all underlying data?

I use `RESTRICT ON DELETE` on some tables to keep consistency, but how do I handle the constraints when I want to delete the complete user account!? Then I get `Integrity constraint violation`

On some tables I also use `CASCADE ON DELETE` so I can't just ignore all constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Start a transaction.
2. For each table that has ON DELETE RESTRICT, delete the right rows. The order of tables sometimes matters; start with the tables "furthest" from the table of users.  (See below.)
3. Then delete the user. ON DELETE CASCADE should delete the remaining
   rows.
4. Commit the transaction.

The order of tables matters when you have a "chain" of tables with ON DELETE RESTRICT.

```
Table_N
    Table_M references Table_N ON DELETE RESTRICT
        Table_P references Table_M ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

You need to delete from Table_P first, then Table_M, then Table_N.